# tilde based exec from a variable

Tags: bash

This sure is something simple but I can't seem to figure out. Any idea what's wrong when I exec the same command via a variable?

this works:

```
$ echo `git --version | cut -d' ' -f3`
1.8.4
```

but this doesn't:

```
$ c="git --version | cut -d' ' -f3"
$ echo  `$c`
git version 1.8.4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the exact reason at my fingertips, but ... you can't do that.

Pipes and redirections seem to be especially special.

However, `eval` will do the job:

```
$ c="git --version | cut -d' ' -f3"
$ eval "$c"
1.7.5.4
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
c="git --version | cut -d' ' -f3"
echo  `$c`
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
git --version "|" cut -d' ' -f3
```

Since the pipe character is inside a variable, it will not get evaluated as a shell metacharacter, and its the same effect as if you typed it on the command line with quotes or backslash to escape it.  This is easier to see if you use this instead:

```
c="echo a b c | wc -w"
echo `$c`
```

As already posted, the answer is to use "eval" so the shell expands the variable and then tries to execute it as shell source, then metacharacters like the pipe will be recognized.